# Saving data from Websocket in Mysql, is better to save in real time or make bulk inserts?

Tags: mysql, websocket, saving-data

I'm receiving data from a websocket and saving it in MySQL.
Currently I'm saving it in real time, I mean, I save it after receiving it, this usually means a multiple inserts with small data in just one second.
I was thinking in collecting the data from the websocket for maybe 500ms, and then make only 2 bulk inserts per second. Is this strategy better than saving in realtime?
If yes/no, can you elaborate why?

Comment: Like every senior says, it depends.